# Any Solutions for the Twitter API1.1 and OAuth for ObjectiveC?

Tags: objective-c, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth, mgtwitterengine

Have an app that is built in xcode and using Objective C, I'm currently using the MGTwitterEngine + OAuthConsumer framework to send out tweets.  Worked great until yesterday when they finally moved to API1.1 and enforced oauth_callback in the OAuth requests.

I can pretty much get around the JSON issue in MGTwitterEngine since it's all source. I reworked it so it sends the JSON request instead of XML for what I need.  The problem is that there is no option for oauth_callback in the OAUTHConsumer framework.  It didn't exist years ago.

I just get Error Domain=HTTP Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)

Anyone building OSX apps (or even iOS) seem to have a fix for this?

Thanks for some pointers.. seems everything for Xcode is about 3 years old.  There were some quick fixes for the API change a while back and I did migrate to those but still nothing for OAUTH.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/) Objective-C library.

It works on OS X and iOS.

It supports Twitter API v.1.1 including the new "App Only" mode.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like OAuthConsumer is out of date.  I have used Sharekit for these tasks and find it to be easy to implement and trouble free.  http://getsharekit.com

Comment: Sharekit looks awesome, sadly it's for iOS and not an OS X app.  Still looking for a solution, seems that my whole Authentication process works but not when sending the updates or any other requests to the server.

Comment: Bryan, Twitter mentioned now "applications to authenticate all of their requests with OAuth", As far as I know MGTwitterEngine only authentication request used OAuth.
Check out this TwitterEngine Code may be its help you.
https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine

Comment: Thanks I found that one too.  None quite work how I want, and I have MGTwitterEngine really buried in with some other OAuth/Twitter code.  Some additional changes along with the JSON throwing a whole wack of errors and it's sort of working again.

Answer (score 0):

From Twitter v1.1 you need to send authentication parameters for all request.. they are updating there api ..you can use this library Click [FHSTwitterEngine](https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine) its working for me as i faced same problem

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me : You have to implement your code as it is like in twitter api 1.0. In new api 1.1, you have to add two jar file twitpic4j.jar and most important twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar. then it's work fine. Enjoy and vote up.

Download jar file from here : http://code.google.com/p/comp3111-project-team201/downloads/detail?name=twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar&can=2&q=

Comment: I have added jar files and also updated API domain to "api.twitter.com/1.1" still getting same error Code=401.Any help.